# How do I find the mode (most frequent element) of an array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, mode

Here is my array:

```
int myArray = new int[5];

myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 1;
myArray[2] = 1;
myArray[3] = 3;
myArray[4] = 5;
```

What do I have to write if I want the program to find the mode of this array?

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C Sharp".

Comment: isn't it how you pronounce it though? @JohnSaunders .

Comment: Mode is the most common value in an array @JeroenVannevel

Comment: Yes, but that's not how you _spell_ it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a LINQ solution:

```
int mode = myArray
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First() // throws InvalidOperationException if myArray is empty
    .Key;
```

This groups the elements of `myArray` by value, sorts the groups by the number of values in each group, and takes the value of the first group. If there is more than one mode, then this takes whichever one occurs first (has the lowest index) in `myArray`.

If there might be more than one mode and you need all of them, then you can use this variation instead:

```
var groups = myArray
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToList(); // materialize the query to avoid evaluating it twice below
int maxCount = groups.Max(g => g.Count); // throws InvalidOperationException if myArray is empty
IEnumerable<int> modes = groups
    .Where(g => g.Count == maxCount)
    .Select(g => g.Value);
```

This groups the elements of `myArray` by value, finds the maximum number of values in any group, and takes the value of every group having that maximum number of values.

If `myArray` is *very* large, then the second version (which is O(n)) might be faster than the first version (which is O(n log n) due to the sort).

Comment: +1. It would be better to use Max-by-count to get `O(n)` for whole operation instead `O(n log n)` due to sorting - but there is no convenient on-line method in LINQ to do that (MoreLINQ have [MaxBy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484563/morelinq-maxby-vs-linq-max-where) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Good point. The duplicated question has an O(n) algorithm which scans the list twice.

Comment: The code worked but what if I don't need the InvalidOperationException since I don't need to check if the array is empty? What should I remove?

Comment: @puretppc: If the array is empty, then technically there is no mode. What do you want the value of `mode` to be in that case?