# How to get Max value from Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to get Max value from Dynamic Linq ?

```
public Func<TSource, T> DynamicMax<TSource, T>(string fieldName, object className)
            {
                var type = typeof(TSource);
                var pe = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
                var propertyReference = Expression.Property(pe, fieldName);
                var constantReference = Expression.Constant(className);

                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, T>>
                    (Expression.IsTrue(propertyReference, constantReference), pe).Compile();
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by max value? Is `T` some sort of collection?

Comment: I also find it quite unclear - can you precize, maybe write in code - what do you exactly expect?

Comment: T is return type,. like string , guid, int ect  & "object className"  has property T inside the class. ex : class person has personNumber property with type string,..

Comment: @SSGeek What is max(string), max(guid)?

Comment: Here, Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484563/morelinq-maxby-vs-linq-max-where